Configuring active passive hub clusters
I'm trying to configure 2 of my openshift hub (acm) clusters to work in active passive mode.
My clusters are installed on-premis. (Servers inside my company).
I started with this documentation. From the above doc, I saw that I need to install the OADP operators.
Thus I installed it on hub-cluster2 and now I'm working with the Custom Resources:
backupStorageLocation - bsl

dataProtectionApplication - dpa.

I want to locate my backups on S3-compatible on premise storage (on ODF).
My Goal:
Is to have the DataProtectionApplication Instance and the BackupStorageLocation Instance work properly.
My problem:
When I run:
oc describe backupStorageLocation -n openshift-adp dpa-sample-1

I can see that openshift reports the error:
Message:               BackupStorageLocation "default" is unavailable: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = RequestError: send request failed

caused by: Get "https://velero-backups.s3.amazonaws.com/?delimiter=%2F&list-type=2&prefix=velero%2F": dial tcp: lookup velero-backups.s3.amazonaws.com on 172.30.X.Y:53: no such host 

Where as indeed openshift is right, the bucket should be
https://ocs-storagecluster-cephobjectstore-openshift-storage.apps.node-hub-test02.opsh-cls.linux.play.local/velero-backups-6374f848-c87e-4368-9904-ed43375ad5ff
This is because when I query the bucket location (from a server in the same domain) I can see the bucket name:
aws --endpoint-url https://ocs-storagecluster-cephobjectstore-openshift-storage.apps.node-hub-test02.opsh-cls.linux.play.local s3 ls

2024-09-25 11:32:23 velero-backups-6374f848-c87e-4368-9904-ed43375ad5ff

When I tried to get rid of the "s3.amazonaws.com" string, by using the "s3ForcePathStyle" I got an error on it:
W0929 17:20:34.664738   19524 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.backupLocations[0].velero.s3ForcePathStyle"
W0929 17:20:34.722556   19524 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.backupLocations[0].velero.s3Url"

My Question:#
How can I configure my system to use the correct S3 address?
THANKS A LOT IN ADVANCE :-)
##############################
oc version

Client Version: 4.9.0-202203251214.p0.ga646be5.assembly.stream-a646be5
Server Version: 4.14.31
Kubernetes Version: v1.27.14+7852426

oc describe dpa -n openshift-adp dpa-sample

Name:         dpa-sample
Namespace:    openshift-adp
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  oadp.openshift.io/v1alpha1
Kind:         DataProtectionApplication
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2024-09-26T09:02:26Z
  Generation:          18
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  oadp.openshift.io/v1alpha1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:configuration:
          .:
          f:nodeAgent:
            .:
            f:enable:
            f:uploaderType:
          f:velero:
    Manager:      Mozilla
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2024-09-29T13:43:02Z
    API Version:  oadp.openshift.io/v1alpha1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:conditions:
    Manager:      manager
    Operation:    Update
    Subresource:  status
    Time:         2024-09-29T13:43:02Z
    API Version:  oadp.openshift.io/v1alpha1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
      f:spec:
        f:backupLocations:
        f:configuration:
          f:velero:
            f:defaultPlugins:
        f:snapshotLocations:
    Manager:         kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2024-09-29T14:20:34Z
  Resource Version:  13682764
  UID:               c3a4fd23-211b-4bb3-b4b8-fc09d25515ab
Spec:
  Backup Locations:
    Name:  default
    Velero:
      Config:
        Profile:  default
        Region:   us-east-1
      Credential:
        Key:    cloud
        Name:   cloud-credentials
      Default:  true
      Object Storage:
        Bucket:  ocs-storagecluster-cephobjectstore-openshift-storage.apps.node-hub-test02.opsh-cls.linux.play.local
        Prefix:  velero
      Provider:  aws
  Configuration:
    Node Agent:
      Enable:         true
      Uploader Type:  restic
    Velero:
      Default Plugins:
        openshift
        aws
  Snapshot Locations:
    Velero:
      Config:
        Profile:  default
        Region:   us-east-1
      Provider:   aws
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2024-09-29T13:43:02Z
    Message:               Reconcile complete
    Reason:                Complete
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Reconciled
Events:                    <none>

oc get bsl -n openshift-adp

NAME           PHASE         LAST VALIDATED   AGE     DEFAULT
default        Unavailable   53s              20h     true
dpa-sample-1   Unavailable   23s              3d22h   true

oc get bsl -A

NAMESPACE       NAME           PHASE         LAST VALIDATED   AGE     DEFAULT
openshift-adp   default        Unavailable   61s              20h     true
openshift-adp   dpa-sample-1   Unavailable   31s              3d22h   true

oc describe bsl dpa-sample-1 -n openshift-adp

Name:         dpa-sample-1
Namespace:    openshift-adp
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/component=bsl
              app.kubernetes.io/instance=dpa-sample-1
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=oadp-operator
              app.kubernetes.io/name=oadp-operator-velero
              openshift.io/oadp=True
              openshift.io/oadp-registry=True
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  velero.io/v1
Kind:         BackupStorageLocation
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2024-09-26T09:02:26Z
  Generation:          5371
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  velero.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .:
          f:app.kubernetes.io/component:
          f:app.kubernetes.io/instance:
          f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by:
          f:app.kubernetes.io/name:
          f:openshift.io/oadp:
          f:openshift.io/oadp-registry:
        f:ownerReferences:
          .:
          k:{"uid":"c3a4fd23-211b-4bb3-b4b8-fc09d25515ab"}:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:config:
          .:
          f:profile:
          f:region:
        f:credential:
        f:default:
        f:objectStorage:
          .:
          f:bucket:
          f:prefix:
        f:provider:
      f:status:
    Manager:      manager
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2024-09-26T09:02:26Z
    API Version:  velero.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:lastValidationTime:
        f:message:
        f:phase:
    Manager:    velero-server
    Operation:  Update
    Time:       2024-09-30T07:11:46Z
  Owner References:
    API Version:           oadp.openshift.io/v1alpha1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  DataProtectionApplication
    Name:                  dpa-sample
    UID:                   c3a4fd23-211b-4bb3-b4b8-fc09d25515ab
  Resource Version:        14838528
  UID:                     70498738-bda3-442b-b8b4-480aa69bf60d
Spec:
  Config:
    Profile:  default
    Region:   us-east-1
  Credential:
    Key:    cloud
    Name:   cloud-credentials
  Default:  true
  Object Storage:
    Bucket:  velero-backups
    Prefix:  velero
  Provider:  aws
Status:
  Last Validation Time:  2024-09-30T07:11:46Z
  Message:               BackupStorageLocation "dpa-sample-1" is unavailable: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Get "https://velero-backups.s3.amazonaws.com/?delimiter=%2F&list-type=2&prefix=velero%2F": dial tcp: lookup velero-backups.s3.amazonaws.com on 172.30.X.Y:53: no such host
  Phase:  Unavailable
Events:   <none>


I resolved the issue. Posting it in case it helps someone else.
The bsl yaml should contain these entries under spec.config:
s3ForcePathStyle: "true"
s3Url: https://The_internal_S3_url
insecureSkipTLSVerify: "True"

